# How to generate a new module in mern.io?

Tags: generator, mern

I've been looking at different MERN (Mongo-Express-React-Node) builds and really like the look of [mern.io](http://mern.io/). I see how everything fits together in a general sense, although the details of the inner-workings often evades me.

When I attempted to modify the base code by manually creating a new module, it was no bueno. The docs indicate that `mern.json` can be used to generate new modules, but does not explain how to do so.

How can this file be used to generate new modules?

Answer (score 3):

The current documentation on mern.io and for the mern-starter is lacking this information. You can however find it in the mern-cli package https://github.com/Hashnode/mern-cli

> Generate React components, Express routes and controllers and Mongoose models using mern generator.
>
> To list out all available generators
>
> > merng

Installation instructions for mern-cli are available in the package README if not already installed. This will allow you to leverage the generators.

Comment: Thank you. I literally invested one hour looking for this.